# String.split, converting Strings to int

Tags: java, arrays, string, converters

I'm looking to have a string.split have 4 parts name1, age1, name2, age2 but turning the "String age1 = parts[1];" and "String age2 = parts[3];" into intergers so I can sort people by age.

Any help would be appreciated!

My code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CharTIntStringSplit
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

       String nameage;

       System.out.println("Enter Firstname and age seperated by , e.g. Firstname, Age");
       nameage = kb.nextLine();

       String[] parts = nameage.split(",");
       String name1 = parts[0];
       String age1 = parts[1];
       String name2 = parts[2];
       String age2 = parts[3];/*after age1 and age2 are converted to 
                              intergers the if statement underneith should work*/

       if (age1 >= age2) {
          System.out.println(name1 + " " + age1 + ", " + name2 + " " + age2);

        }

       else if (age1 < age2)  {
           System.out.println(name2 + " " + age2 + ", " + name1 + " " + age1);

       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look into the `parseInt` method of the `Integer` class.

Comment: I have tried that, I couldn't really understand as I'm a beginner, could you maybe link to a post that explains it simply for me =)  Thanks

Comment: I could google it for you, yes.  I'm not going to.

Comment: Lol thnx anyway, haha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Integer.parseInt(String s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) method to convert a valid number string to int value. Here is a sample:

```
int intAge1 = Integer.parseInt(age1);
```

Note that this method throws `NumberFormatException` in case the input string is not a valid number.

Comment: @SamsinOzo Glad it helped..just accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark left to my answer. Accepting an answer helps others facing the same problem.

Comment: Yeah I tried to earlier but it wouldn't allow me since it had only been 6 minutes, thanks again for the help

Comment: Already hit another issue with it while trying to loop the string, I've hit this issue before but fixed it by firing an empty Scanner.nextLine doing that this time did not fix the error, I think it's because 1st time it only had 2 parts, this one has 4, time to research!  :3

Answer (score 1):

do this:

```
int age1 = Integer.valueOf(parts[1]).intValue();
```

Integer.valueOf(parts[1]) will convert the string to the object Integer.
the .intValue() method will convert the Integer object to the primitive int type.

do the same to the attribute age2.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to convert the String to int using

```
int x = Integer.parseInt("String that you want to convert to int");
```

I would suggest you to look into the API and see the java docs on how this works.